# Sending device to device with urbanairship using android and PHP

Tags: php, android, urbanairship.com

I am using this code

```
define('APPKEY','XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); 
define('PUSHSECRET', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX '); // Master Secret
define('PUSHURL', 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/'); 


$msg = "This is a message intended for my iPad 3";

$devicetokens = array();
$devicetokens[0] = $devicetoken;

$contents = array(); 
$contents['badge'] = "1"; 
$contents['alert'] = $msg; 
$contents['sound'] = "default"; 

$push = array("aps" => $contents, "device_tokens" =>$devicetokens); 


$json = json_encode($push); 
$session = curl_init(PUSHURL); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, APPKEY . ':' . PUSHSECRET); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, True); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, False); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json')); 
$content = curl_exec($session); 

var_dump($content); // just for testing what was sent

 // Check if any error occured 
$response = curl_getinfo($session);
```

But nothing happens - i get "device_token contains an invalid device token" ERROR

Does the device token need to be sent in a particular JSON format ? I can't find any documentation for this method . I got it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698608/urban-airship-send-push-to-1-specific-device-device-token)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it working

The correct format is [here](http://docs.urbanairship.com/connect/android_push.html#push)

Needed to change the order and names of the JSON object and attributes

```
$msg = "This is a message intended for Nexus";

$devicetokens    = array(); 
$devicetoken     = "YOUR DEVICE TOKEN"; 
$devicetokens[0] = $devicetoken;

$contents = array(); 
$contents['alert'] = $msg; 
$contents['sound'] = "default";

$push = array("apids" =>$devicetokens, "android" => $contents);

$json = json_encode($push);
```